The docker container (superset) from inside Ubuntu WSL2 on Win 10 does not see the port of the Win host
Supetset deployed in a docker container inside  WSL2 Ubuntu running on Win 10:
Step 1:
sudo docker pull apache/superset

Step 2:
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8088 -e "SUPERSET_SECRET_KEY=your_secret_key_here" --name superset apache/superset

Step 3:
sudo docker exec -it superset superset fab create-admin \
           --username admin \
           --firstname Superset \
           --lastname Admin \
           --email admin@admin.com \
           --password postgres123; \
sudo docker exec -it superset superset db upgrade; \
sudo docker exec -it superset superset load_examples; \
sudo docker exec -it superset superset init;

Login into superset from the Win host being without any problems:
http://localhost:8080/login

On Win 10:
Adapter Ethernet vEthernet (WSL):
IPv4-adress. . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.192.1
Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0

5433 port is open.
From WSL2 Ubuntu inside Win 10:
slubun@msknb51:~$ route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         172.17.192.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
    172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
    172.17.192.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0


slubun@msknb51:~$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            inet 172.17.194.48  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.17.207.255

slubun@msknb51:~$ telnet 172.17.192.1 5433
    Trying 172.17.192.1...
    Connected to 172.17.192.1.
    Escape character is '^]'.

postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf are OK:
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
    port = 5433             # (change requires restart)

and
host    all             all             172.17.194.48/20            trust

I can't access from superset container inside WSL2 Ubuntu to the postgresql server on the Win host:
172.17.192.1 port 5433


Error: "The port is closed".

